# Certain websites will not work on any browser

Tags: 18.04

I have Ubuntu 18.04.5, and suddenly a couple days ago some websites stopped working on my computer. I tried in different browsers too which resulted in the same outcome. I tried to change the mtu in Tilda with

```
ifconfig <dev> mtu 1400
```

but it says

```
bash: dev: No such file or directory
```

I am very new to Ubuntu and don't know how to troubleshoot this.

I would greatly appreciate any help!!

Comment: `<dev>` is supposed to be device name, i.e. `eth0`, `eth1`, `wlan`, etc.  Just run `ifconfig` with nothing after it and it will show you all your network devices.

Comment: What make you think than changing  MTU will fix anything ?

Comment: @SorenA it was just what I Found as I was looking for solutions to this problem

Comment: Are all web sites or only specific web sites not coming up for you?  Since you are at a college is there someone else you can test with theirs to see if maybe it might be a firewall / site filter that the college might be doing?

Answer (score 0):

Try unplugging your modem or router for 30 seconds so it does a clean restart when you plug it back in. This needs to be done occasionally anyway. Just updating the packages as @RingGamesCompany kindly suggests will not bring the packages up to date. `sudo apt update` will only tell you if your packages are up to date or what packages need updating. You also need to use `sudo apt upgrade` to upgrade the packages so the system can bring them up to date. You can do both of these commands with this single command: `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`. Some packages (like browsers) require a [Restart] before the upgrade will take full effect. Plus, a new installation of Ubuntu does not necessarily install all the latest upgrades. So, I suggest you do these commands (they only take seconds) and plan on doing a [Restart] after running them. Your entire system will probably run faster afterwards. Should doing the update, upgrade and [Restart] fail to solve the problem, your modem or router may need more time to warm up after startup. The Ubuntu operating system loads much faster than others and so your modem or router may not have warmed up enough after you system is up and running to connect to all websites. I too use Ubuntu 18.04.5 and occasionally my modem fools me in this way. It looks like the modem is working because the computer loads links I use all the time from the cache. Mine usually takes a few minutes after the system is up and running to warm up enough to load new links. Also, clicking reload/refresh on the page that failed may solve the problem as there may be a failed copy of it in your cache. If so, your computer keeps loading the failed page. Reload/refresh goes to the website and reloads it from scratch and updates the cache. Finally, the trouble may be with the links you are using to go to these websites. Have you checked if the websites you are having trouble with are working for others? If not, copy and paste a link or two here so someone can check them for you. Re-installing a package or Operating System should only be done after all else fails. The side effects may be worse than the problem. Installing a new version of an Operating System should only be done if you want or have to. I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: thank you so much for your thorough response. Unfortunately I am living on a college campus atm and don't have access to the modem or router in my room. The websites I'm trying to use are all working on my chromebook just not my laptop with Ubuntu on it. I will be trying to use my computer at my friend's place tomorrow and see if I'm still having those issues. If not, I'm only at this college until next Friday, so would you still recommend re-installing the OS?? Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: I do not recommend re-installing the OS. I suggest trying Refresh on pages that don't load. If that doesn't work. Run sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y  and do a [Restart] to upgrade all your packages. It's a good practice to upgrade them occasionally (once a quarter or so) anyway. Upgrading packages only looks for packages (programs) that have an improved version. It does not change the OS in any way.

Answer (score -1):

I think use firefox. And it seems you are using 18.04, a much older version of Ubuntu, so i'd suggest upgrade your system.

Also, note,go to terminal and then type in `sudo apt update` and this will update your files so that might work. If not, just try reinstalling the application

Comment: `sudo apt update` updates the package database, not the actual packages. After running `sudo apt update`run `sudo apt upgrade` to do the actual package update.

Comment: Also, there should not be any issue with an older but supported version of Ubuntu because it would still have the latest version of firefox or chromium.

Comment: 18.04 is not EOL till April 2023 upgrade is not the answer to everything.